# notifyDataSetChanged() not working with recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm using Recyclerview in one of my activity, but I'm not able to show any data in recyclerView.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:id="@+id/toolBar">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_back_light"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sushi"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/chatMessages"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolBar"
        android:layout_above="@+id/messageInputView"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:paddingStart="12dp"
        android:paddingEnd="12dp"
        android:id="@+id/messageInputView">

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:paddingStart="12dp"
            android:paddingEnd="12dp"
            android:background="#D9D9D9"
            android:id="@+id/border"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/messageInput"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/messageSendButton"
            android:hint="Type a message..."
            android:textColorHint="#80282a2b"
            android:inputType="textAutoCorrect|textAutoComplete|textMultiLine|textCapSentences"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/messageSendButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_send"
            android:onClick="onClick"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
            android:background="@drawable/send_message_background"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

All callback methods of `RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>` not calling on calling `notifydatasetchanged()`.

Adapter code here :

```
    public class ChatMessagesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>  {

    private static String TAG = "ChatMessagesAdapter";
    private ArrayList<ChatMessages> mChatMessages;
    private Context mContext;

    public ChatMessagesAdapter(ArrayList<ChatMessages> chatMessages, Context context){
        mContext = context.getApplicationContext();
        mChatMessages = chatMessages;
        Log.d("ChatActivity Adapter", String.valueOf(mChatMessages.size()));
        setHasStableIds(true);
    }

    public synchronized void refreshData(ArrayList<ChatMessages> feeds){
        Log.d("ChatActivity Adapter", String.valueOf(feeds.size()));
        mChatMessages.clear();
        mChatMessages.addAll(feeds);
        Log.d("ChatActivity Adapter", String.valueOf(mChatMessages.size()));
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    class IncomingMessageHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        @BindView(R.id.messageText) TextView mMessageText;
        @BindView(R.id.messageTime) TextView mMessageTime;

        IncomingMessageHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this,itemView);
        }
    }

    class OutgoingMessageHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        @BindView(R.id.messageText) TextView mMessageText;
        @BindView(R.id.messageTime) TextView mMessageTime;

        OutgoingMessageHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this,itemView);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        Log.d("ChatActivity Adapter","getItemViewType "+mChatMessages.get(position).getMessageStatus());
        if (mChatMessages.get(position).getMessageStatus() == 2){
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Log.d("ChatActivity Adapter","onCreateViewHolder");
        switch (viewType){
            case 0 :
                View outgoingMessageView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_outcoming_text_message,parent,false);
                return new OutgoingMessageHolder(outgoingMessageView);
            default :
                View incomingMessageView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_incoming_text_message, parent, false);
                return new IncomingMessageHolder(incomingMessageView);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Log.d("ChatActivity Adapter","onBindViewHolder");
        switch (holder.getItemViewType()){
            case 0:
                OutgoingMessageHolder outgoingMessageHolder = (OutgoingMessageHolder) holder;
                outgoingMessageHolder.mMessageText.setText(mChatMessages.get(position).getMessage());
                outgoingMessageHolder.mMessageTime.setText(
                        UtilsFuntions.getDurationString(mChatMessages.get(position).getTimeStamp())
                );
                break;
            case 1:
                IncomingMessageHolder incomingMessageHolder = (IncomingMessageHolder) holder;
                incomingMessageHolder.mMessageText.setText(mChatMessages.get(position).getMessage());
                incomingMessageHolder.mMessageTime.setText(
                        UtilsFuntions.getDurationString(mChatMessages.get(position).getTimeStamp())
                );
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        Log.d("ChatActivity Adapter", String.valueOf(mChatMessages.size()));
        return mChatMessages.size();
    }

}
```

Code for initalizing recyclerView:

```
mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
    mLayoutManager.setItemPrefetchEnabled(true);
    mChatMessages.setItemViewCacheSize(0);
    mChatMessages.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    mChatMessages.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
    mChatMessages.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mChatMessages.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mChatMessagesAdapter = new ChatMessagesAdapter(mChatItems,
            getApplicationContext());
    mChatMessages.addOnScrollListener(listerOnScroll);
    mChatMessages.setAdapter(mChatMessagesAdapter);

    ChatMessages chatMessage = new ChatMessages();
                chatMessage.setMessage(mChatMessage.getText().toString().trim());
                chatMessage.setMessageStatus(2);
                chatMessage.setTimeStamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
                mChatItems.add(chatMessage);
                mChatMessagesAdapter.refreshData(mChatItems);
```

**But when** even I touch recyclerview or try to scroll recyclerview all callbacks called and recyclerview get populated. I don't know why this is happening. Please help me to solve this

Comment: add the code where you are setuping the recyclerview

Comment: show the code where you are initializing the adapter. Also want to know from where you are calling 'refreshData'

Comment: Code updated for recyclerview setup

Comment: how did you populate the value of `mChatItems`, check if `mChatItems` is empty-- what is the value in logcat for this `Log.d("ChatActivity Adapter", String.valueOf(mChatMessages.size()));`

Comment: @NavneetKrishna `ChatMessages chatMessage = new ChatMessages();
                    chatMessage.setMessage(mChatMessage.getText().toString().trim());
                    chatMessage.setMessageStatus(2);
                    chatMessage.setTimeStamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
                    mChatItems.add(chatMessage);
                    mChatMessagesAdapter.refreshData(mChatItems);`

Comment: I would start with deleting these lines mChatMessages.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    mChatMessages.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);

Comment: Problem solved, it is due to some threading problems